# Python Object Changing For No Apparent Reason

Tags: python

Edit: I'm very stupid - forgot that I declared keys twice. Declaring the same key twice will not throw an error; it will overwrite the previously defined key.

I create a dict of various objects...
Everytime I run the script (I have checked that the file updating), the second index of the first few objects in the dict are changed. I am not changing them anywhere in my code. I threw the dict and print into a separate python file with nothing else and I still got the same results.

```py
checklist = {
        "pine logs": ['logs', '2', '4'],
        "travertine": ['rocks', '2', '4'],
        "iron ore": ['ores', '2', '4'],
        "medium hide": ['hides', '2', '4'],
        "hemp": ['fibers', '2', '4'],
        "pine logs": ['logs', '3', '4'],
        "travertine": ['rocks', '3', '4'],
        "iron ore": ['ores', '3', '4'],
        "medium hide": ['hides', '3', '4'],
        "hemp": ['fibers', '3', '4'],
        "cedar logs": ['logs', '1', '5'],
        "granite": ['rocks', '1', '5'],
        "titanium ore": ['ores', '1', '5'],
        "heavy hide": ['hides', '1', '5'],
        "skyflower": ['fibers', '1', '5'],
        "cedar logs": ['logs', '2', '5'],
        "granite": ['rocks', '2', '5'],
        "titanium ore": ['ores', '2', '5'],
        "heavy hide": ['hides', '2', '5'],
        "skyflower": ['fibers', '2', '5'],
        "bloodoak logs": ['logs', '1', '6'],
        "slate": ['rocks', '1', '6'],
        "runite ore": ['ores', '1', '6'],
        "robust hide": ['hides', '1', '6'],
        "redleaf cotton": ['fibers', '1', '6'],
        "bloodoak logs": ['logs', '2', '6'],
        "slate": ['rocks', '2', '6'],
        "runite ore": ['ores', '2', '6'],
        "robust hide": ['hides', '2', '6'],
        "redleaf cotton": ['fibers', '2', '6'],
        "ashenbark logs": ['logs', '1', '7'],
        "basalt": ['rocks', '1', '7'],
        "meteorite ore": ['ores', '1', '7'],
        "thick hide": ['hides', '1', '7'],
        "sunflax": ['fibers', '1', '7'],
        "ashenbark logs": ['logs', '2', '7'],
        "basalt": ['rocks', '2', '7'],
        "meteorite ore": ['ores', '2', '7'],
        "thick hide": ['hides', '2', '7'],
        "sunflax": ['fibers', '2', '7']
    }
    print(checklist)
```

output:

```py
{'pine logs': ['logs', '3', '4'], 'travertine': ['rocks', '3', '4'], 'iron ore': ['ores', '3', '4'], 'medium hide': ['hides', '3', '4'], 'hemp': ['fibers', '3', '4'], 'cedar logs': ['logs', '2', '5'], 'granite': ['rocks', '2', '5'], 'titanium ore': ['ores', '2', '5'], 'heavy hide': ['hides', '2', '5'], 'skyflower': ['fibers', '2', '5'], 'bloodoak logs': ['logs', '2', '6'], 'slate': ['rocks', '2', '6'], 'runite ore': ['ores', '2', '6'], 'robust hide': ['hides', '2', '6'], 'redleaf cotton': ['fibers', '2', '6'], 'ashenbark logs': ['logs', '2', '7'], 'basalt': ['rocks', '2', '7'], 'meteorite ore': ['ores', '2', '7'], 'thick hide': ['hides', '2', '7'], 'sunflax': ['fibers', '2', '7']}
```

Why is index 1 of the first few objects in the dict changing? I even tried changing the `'2'` to `'two'` but it still ends up as `'2'`.

Comment: You declare 'pine logs' twice.

Comment: You have "pine logs" and "travertine" in the dictionary twice.  When the same element is repeated, the second once overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate keys in the dict defintion.  In this case, the later values will override the earlier ones.  For example:

```
checklist = {
        "pine logs": ['logs', '2', '4'],
        ...
        "pine logs": ['logs', '3', '4'],
        ...
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
checklist = {
        ...
        "pine logs": ['logs', '3', '4'],
        ...
}
```

If you want to have multiple instances of the same key, you can either keep a list of value lists for each key, or you can switch to a list representation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **for** loop and select what results you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary `checklist` violates the unique key constrain (duplicate `pine logs`):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with
> the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).[1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)